# ggseasonplot in R forecast not showing forecast when last unit of time has only 1 observation

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, forecasting

When using the ggseasonplot from for forecast package, it works as desired when there are 2 or more observations per unit of time (ie 2+ quarters in a year).

For example

```
austres  %>% ggseasonplot()
```

yeilds

[image: 1993 shown in legend and plotted]

However, if we remove the Q2-1993 (so our last observation is Q1-1993), we see 1993 on the legend, but not on the plot. Should it be showing up as a point? If so, how would I put it in?

```
austres %>% window(end=c(1993,1)) %>% ggseasonplot()
```

[image: 1993 shown in legend but NOT plotted]

Answer (score 1):

***I have found a way to do it-- but I don't know if if is 
the simplest way to do it!***

I modified the code in [ggseasonplot on github](https://github.com/robjhyndman/forecast/blob/5e1dd0797e54ff92b6b24e5d5751e2b91e39f221/R/ggplot.R])

```
tspx <- tsp(austres %>% window(end=c(1993,1)))
s <- round(frequency(x))
x <- ts(austres, start = tspx[1], frequency = s)

data <- data.frame(
  y = as.numeric(x),
  year = trunc(time(x)),
  cycle = as.numeric(cycle(x)),
  time = as.numeric((cycle(x) - 1) / s)
)

austres %>% window(end=c(1993,1)) %>% ggseasonplot()+
  layer(
    data[nrow(data)-1,] ,
    geom = "point",
    stat = "identity",
    position = "identity", aes(x= time,y=y,col="1993")
  )
```

Doing so yields this plot, which is what I wanted

[image: Image showing successful Q1 point]